# Get filtered array of objects from array of values

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to filter the `inventory` array based on the values I have in the `cars` array. The result currently I'm getting is `[]`.

```js
const cars = ['s', 'y']

const inventory = [{
  desc: 'Tesla',
  customers: [{
    model: 's',
    name: 'John'
  }]
}, {
  desc: 'Audi',
  customers: [{
    model: 'q3',
    name: 'Doe'
  }]
}]

const result = inventory.filter((val) => {
cars.includes(val.customers.map((val) => val.model))
})

console.log(result)
```

The result what I'm expecting is below. Could anyone please help?

```
[{
  desc: 'Tesla',
  customers: [{
    model: 's',
    name: 'John'
  }]
}]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is with the `filter()` function. The `map()` function inside `includes()` returns an array, so you need to use the `some()` function to check if any of the customer models match the cars array.

```
const cars = ['s', 'y']

const inventory = [{
  desc: 'Tesla',
  customers: [{
    model: 's',
    name: 'John'
  }]
}, {
  desc: 'Audi',
  customers: [{
    model: 'q3',
    name: 'Doe'
  }]
}]

const result = inventory.filter((val) => {
  return val.customers.some((customer) => cars.includes(customer.model))
})

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `filter` with `reduce` with and `includes`:

```js
const cars = ['s', 'y']

const inventory = [{
  desc: 'Tesla',
  customers: [{
    model: 's',
    name: 'John'
  }]
}, {
  desc: 'Audi',
  customers: [{
    model: 'q3',
    name: 'Doe'
  }]
}]

const result = inventory.filter((item) =>
  item.customers.reduce((acc, curr) => acc || cars.includes(curr.model), false))

console.log(result)
```